# How to change the language used within the Cygwin terminal?

Tags: gcc, configuration, cygwin, locale

When I'm using `gcc` in *Cygwin* I'm getting error messages in Russian which, for instance, looks like the following:

```
$ gcc -Wall kmeans.c -o kmeans
kmeans.c:260:1: предупреждение: неявное приведение большого целого значения к беззнаковому типу [-Woverflow]
 size_t used_size = ULLONG_MAX; // size of each file used, binary file only
```

However I prefer to work in English. Thus, how can I change permanently the language that is used within the *Cygwin* terminal?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try set env variable: `LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'`

Reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables/

Comment: It works, but I need to write it at every start if cygwin terminal, can it be done once and for forever?

Comment: that helped http://superuser.com/questions/374892/cygwin-bash-g-is-in-japanese-mode-how-to-set-everything-to-english

Comment: Of course you can, just add it to `~/.bash_profile` - that file is read every time terminal starts.

Comment: For Windows10 users, create a new environment variable, where the variable name is `LANG`, the variable value is `en_GB.URF-8`.

Comment: Hi, my 'Downloads' folder name is in Korea (다운로드) and my 'Desktop' folder name is in Korean (바탕화면). Can I change those folder names automatically to English or should I change them manually?

Comment: @ChanKim you should change ur system language then ;)

Answer (score 22):

adding:

```
export LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'
```

to:

```
~/.bashrc
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was fixed after changing locale (en_GB) and character set (UTF-8) on the Text page of the `mintty` Options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is:

```
export LC_ALL=C; unset LANGUAGE
```